# Solving $2\sin a\cos a+1=2\cos a+\sin a$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the value of $a$ in this equation:
> $$2\sin a\cos a+1=2\cos a+\sin a$$

I've tried squaring or writing $1$ as $\sin^2a+\cos^2a$, but still can't figure out the result. Finding the primary value of $a$ will be enough. I can work on the quadrants.

Comment: Move everything to one side of the equation, then factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${\quad 2\sin a\cos a+1=2\cos a+\sin a\\\Rightarrow 2\sin a\cos a-2\cos a-\sin a+1=0\\\Rightarrow2\cos a(\sin a-1)-(\sin a-1)=0\\\Rightarrow(\sin a-1)(2\cos a-1)=0}$$

I think you can continue thereafter.

Comment: Now I feel so dumb to ask this question

Comment: @Md.SayanKhan, No need to feel like that. Some time we think in complex way for a simple question which is normal. Next time try twice before asking a question if you fail then Mathematics Stack Exchange community is always happy to answer good questions.